# Data in LocalStorage gets overwritten when login from a second window in localhost

Tags: jquery, redirect, local-storage

When on **submit** (index.html) I do the following **ajax** I need to save the **user data** to **localStorage**, since I **redirect** to another **route**, it won't have the the **data** unless. This all works fine, but when I open the page in a new **localhost window** and I **login** again my old data in **localStorage** gets overwritten.

Why does that happen?

```
// Login index.js 
$('#frm-login').submit(function (e) {
    event.preventDefault()
    $('button').text('Please wait ...').prop('disabled')
    $.ajax({
        url: "/login-user",
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#frm-login').serialize(),
        dataType: "json"
    }).always(function (response) {
        $('button').text('Logging in').prop('disabled')
        console.log("Login", response)
        if (response.status == "error") {
            $('button').removeClass('lime').addClass('red').text('Log in failed. Try again.');
            return
        }
        if (response.token) {
            localStorage.setItem('token', response.token);
            console.log(localStorage.token)
            if (localStorage.token) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/verify-user",
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.token
                    },
                    dataType: "json"
                }).always(function (response) {
                    console.log("Auth", response)
                    if (response.status == "error") {
                        $('button').removeClass('lime').addClass('red').text('Log in failed. Try again.');
                        return
                    }
                    if (response.status == 302) {
                        console.log(response)
                        $jUser = response.responseJSON.authData.user
                        $sjUser = JSON.stringify($jUser);
                        localStorage.setItem('user', $sjUser);
                        $(location).attr('pathname', '/LIMELine/chatroom/')
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Getting data from localStorage **main.js**

```
$jUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.user)
$('#frame #sidepanel #profile-img').attr('src', $jUser.avatar)
$('#frame #sidepanel #profile .wrap #full-name').text($jUser.first_name + ' ' + $jUser.last_name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localStorage` is shared across all tabs for the given domain.  If you do not want this to be the case, you can use `sessionStorage` instead.  However, as a side effect of using `sessionStorage`, the data will be destroyed when the window/tag it is associated with closes.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

> The read-only localStorage property allows you to access a Storage object for the Document's origin; the stored data is saved across browser sessions. localStorage is similar to sessionStorage, except that while data stored in localStorage has no expiration time, data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends — that is, when the page is closed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

> The sessionStorage property allows you to access a session Storage object for the current origin. sessionStorage is similar to Window.localStorage; the only difference is while data stored in localStorage has no expiration set, data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends. A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores. Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated, which differs from how session cookies work.

Comment: thank you. I really didn't know this difference between them. Are there other differences?

Comment: Those are the primary differences that I am aware of.  localStorage you can think of sorta as an alternative to cookies.  sessionStorage the same, but with the smaller scope and life span.